# Executing a script when user opens certain webpage

Tags: python

How can I make my program execute only when a certain webpage is opened.? For example I want to execute my program only when I visit the webpage `www.google.com`.
So far I made my program execute only when the given webpage is up by using the lines below, but how can I execute only when user view the page google.com?

```
loop_value = 1
while (loop_value == 1):
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        loop_value = 0
        main()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want your script to execute if you visit google.com in e.g. Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: exactly. regardless of any browser.

Comment: I'm not really sure if that's possible with Python alone. You'd either need a binding with the browser, or somehow intercept GET requests that your machine sends.

Comment: I wanted the way by which I can intercept the GET requests.. Any links to get idea, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just python cannot directly see what webpages are being accessed unless the user goes through `urllib2` or something of the likes.

---

Instead, try accessing it with an overlay of JavaScript or something of the likes, and then you can trigger your python script with that.

Or, as @pbackup said,

> You can set up transparent proxy to intercept the traffic

Comment: Unless he had it sit in the background and check all the processes. Even then it would be reliant on how the processes are displayed and I'm pretty sure the browsers don't list what webpages they are visiting from a ps perspective.

Comment: You can set up transparent proxy to intercept the traffic.

Comment: @pbackup will add that

Comment: But the transparent proxy will only work for `http://google.com`, not `https://google.com`.

Comment: Intercepting the traffic by setting up transparent proxy is what I needed. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Rob Unsless you decrypt the traffic. Fiddler does it.